# Weird numbers in C++ array of objects

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management

I've been trying to make an class with an array of objects created dynamically. I overloaded the operator + to add (only this for now) a new object to a group of objects (class to class). THe problem is when I read the data in the array, I get all sorts of big numbers . Here is the code:

```
#include<iostream.h>

class Figura {
    public: 
        int x, y, poz;
        int tip; //1 = punct ; 2 = dreapta; 3 = dreptunghi
        Figura() { };
        Figura(const Figura&) { };
};

class Grup {
    private:
        int nr_elemente;
        Figura *figuri;
    public:
        int i;
        Grup(int nr_el) {
            nr_elemente = nr_el;
            figuri = new Figura[nr_elemente];
            i = 1;
        }
        ~Grup() {};
        Grup(const Grup&) {};
        int _nr_elemente() {
            return i;
        }

        void adauga_element(Figura fig) {
            if( i <= nr_elemente)
                figuri[i++] = fig;
            else
                cout<<"Grupul a atins numarul maxim de figuri.";
        }

        void afiseaza_elemente() {
            for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
                cout<<"Figura nr : "<<j<<"tip: "<<figuri[j].tip<<figuri[j].x<<" "<<figuri[j].y<<" "<<figuri[j].poz;
        }
    friend Grup operator+(const Figura& fig1, const Figura& fig2) {
        return fig1.poz + fig2.poz;
    };
    friend Grup operator+(const Grup& gr1, const Grup& gr2) {};
    void operator+(const Figura& fig);
    friend Grup operator*(const Grup& fig) {};

};

void Grup::operator+(const Figura& fig) {
    Grup::adauga_element(fig);
}

class Punct : public Figura
{
    public: 
        Punct(int poz) {
            Punct::tip = 1;
            Punct::poz = poz;
        }
};

class Segment : public Figura
{
    public:
        Segment(int poz, int x) {
            Segment::tip = 2;
            Segment::poz = poz;
            Segment::x = x;
        }
};

class Dreptunghi : public Figura
{
    public:
        Dreptunghi(int poz, int x, int y) {
            Dreptunghi::tip = 3;
            Dreptunghi::poz = poz;
            Dreptunghi::x = x;
            Dreptunghi::y = y;
        }
};

void main(void) {

    Grup gr(1);
    Punct pct(1);
    Segment sgm(3, 5);

    gr + pct;
    gr + sgm;
    //cout<<gr.i;
    cout<<sgm.x;
    gr.afiseaza_elemente();

}
```

Comment: It will be used for like maximum 10-15 elements.

Comment: You need to still allocate more memory for figuri, but even better would be to declare figuri as a vector. And you should really look into using [initialization lists](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html)

Comment: If your class is supposed to represent a dynamic array, that kind of ruins the point. If you can, use `std::vector` in place of making your own class, and just `push_back` each element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more simple example would improve understanding.

In any case, your problem is known as object slicing.

In short, you cannot put a derived object in an array of base objects.

To solve the problem you can change the figuri data member to be an array of pointers to Figura:

```
Figura ** figuri;
// ...
figuri = new Figura*[nr_elemente];
```

Comment: I've made some modifications based on the code above, but one last question. How can I adapt this chunk of code so I can add objects to the array: void add(Figura fig) { figuri[i++] = fig; }

Answer (score 4):

Array indexes run from `0` to `N - 1`, when `N` is the array size. The following code will result  in out of bounds array access:

```
void adauga_element(Figura fig) {
    if( i <= nr_elemente)
        figuri[i++] = fig;
    else
        cout<<"Grupul a atins numarul maxim de figuri.";
}
```

Change to:

```
    if( i < nr_elemente)
```

Same problem in `afiseaza_elemente()`.

As you have dynamically allocated members a destructor must `delete[]` the dynamically allocated array and a copy constructor and assignment operator need to be correctly implemented, or declared `private` to prevent copying. As this is C++, consider using `std::vector<Figura>` instead of an array.

Comment: ...same problem in the 'print' method (i.e. `afiseaza_elemente`), too.

Answer (score 0):

You're not initializing any members. You should do that in the constructor.

For example:

```
Punct pct(1);
```

only initializes the members `tip` and `pos`, but `x` and `y` will contain garbage values, which you probably end up seeing.

You also shouldn't be using a dynamically allocated array as a member - `Figura *figuri;` but a `std::vector`. This would save you also from the undefined behavior you're encountering when adding new figures.

Also, note that your destructors and copy constructors have no implementation, which is a source for bugs.

```
void adauga_element(Figura fig)
```

passes the object `fig` is passed by value, so a copy constructor should be implemented.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific please?